# How to remove material and faces that are textured by it?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I have a huge mesh with many-many textures and vertices. I would like to remove a material and all the faces using it (from the mesh). How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *EDIT MODE*

1. Select one face having assigned the material to remove.
2. Select -> Similar (<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>) -> Material
3. <kbd>X</kbd>

Python:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.select_similar(type='MATERIAL', threshold=0.01)
```

Note: The operator has a few option you see in the left panel left:

[image] [image]